# Is there a way to run filters on arbitrary methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, callback, sinatra, ruby-1.9.3

```
after_create   :send_email
```

works fine, but what if you want to have a filter on a different method?

```
class User
  def update_name new_name
    name = new_name
  end

  def send_email
    ...
```

Is there a way to create an after filter (to send_email) on the update method?

Why not just put send_email in update_name? Because update_name is in a separate module. I don't want to pollute that module with code that has to do with the user.

Working in Ruby 1.9.3 and Sinatra, not Rails.

Comment: You want an `after_m :some_method` for an arbitrary method `m` on an arbitrary class?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I tried it but got `undefined method after_m`.

Comment: add "send_email" at the end of the update method? :)  What library is after_create coming from?

Comment: @rogerdpack: He wants to have ActiveModel style callbacks on arbitrary classes. At least that's my take on it.

Comment: I guess this is the best way: https://github.com/apotonick/hooks/